# Pinia $subscribe miss mutations when working with multiple Stores simultaneously

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I have created a **plugin** for **subscribing** to all the **Stores State** and when the **state** change it's saved to **indexedDB**

The plugin is:

```
import ofcDB from 'boot/indexeddb';

export async function IndexedDbPlugin(context) {

  context.store.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
        const toStorage = serializer.serialize(state));
         ofcDB.collection(storeName).doc(storeId).set(toStorage);
    
  });
}
```

With this **plugin** registered as  `pinia.use(IndexedDbPlugin);` it is assumed that when each **Store** changes its **state**, it should be **stored** in **indexedDB**.

It works fine when I make changes in a **single Store** but when for example simultaneous changes are made in 2 Stores it only updates one.

For example I have 2 Stores (**ProjectStore** and **GoalStore**) and when I create a **Goal** in a **project** it is created in **GoalStore** and added to **ProjectStore**.

These operations are performed from **GoalStore**:

```
import { useProjectStore } from "../project/ProjectStore";

export const useGoalStore = defineStore("GoalStore", {
  state: () => ({
    goals: null, 
  }),

 actions: {
   createItem(Goal) {
     this.goals.push(Goal);
     const ProjectStore = useProjectStore();
     ProjectStore.addItem(Goal);
   }
  }
})
```

So, when the createItem method is called:

1. The **Goal** is added to the **GoalStore State**.
2. The **ProjectStore** **addItem** method is called, which in turn updates the **state** in **ProjectStore**.

The problem is that only the **state** of **ProjectStore** is **updated** in **indexedDB** and not the **state** of **GoalStore** when  **$subscribe** should work for both.

Am I omitting some important detail?

Thanks